# Two different gateways and ping from passive one in Linux

Tags: linux, networking, routes, ping, gateway

I have two different default gateways for different network interfaces like below

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask   Flags Metric Ref   Use  Iface
0.0.0.0         172.16.18.1     0.0.0.0   UG    10      0     0   wlp0s20f0u3
0.0.0.0         192.168.13.1    0.0.0.0   UG    5       0     0   enp3s0
```

The second one has low metric value and it means my active network interface is enp3s0.My queistion is that how to check internet connection using the first(passive) network interface when the second is active ? When i use the

```
ping -I wlp0s20f0u3 www.google.com
```

It cannot ping google. But when i use

```
ping -I enp3s0 www.google.com
```

I got the answer from ping. Why the first ping command is not working ?

Someone can help me ?

Comment: what did you got from first ping?

Comment: I didnt get any response.Response line :  PING www.google.com (216.58.212.4) from 172.16.18.216 wlp0s20f0u3: 56(84) bytes of data

Comment: you should try `traceroute` to see if gateway is available or where packetes got dropped.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved my problem by the help of following link

https://www.thomas-krenn.com/en/wiki/Two_Default_Gateways_on_One_System

And now i am using
    ping -I wlp0s20f0u3 www.google.com 
when the enp3s0 interface is active.